# How to solve: dpkg error exit status 1 while processing linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic

Tags: linux-mint

I just installed Linux Mint on mi laptop. When I try to update the system or install language packages I get errors related to linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic.

For example, if I execute the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (I found this to solve the error in some webpages, but it doesn't work and is a way to reproduce the error), I get:

```
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (5.4.0-77.86) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (5.4.0-77.86) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-77-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb3
I: (UUID=d98bd037-090b-4643-8d5d-f0db45378205)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic
```

Operating System Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon 
Cinamon Version 4.8.6
Linux Kernel 5.4.0-74-generic
Processor Intel© Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Memory 15.5 GiB
Hard Drives 1756.4 GB
Graphics Card Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

Comment: Do you have enough disk space in `/boot`? What does `df -h /boot` say?

Comment: Sometimes I recieved a warning about that. Your command returns: Filesystem /dev/sdb            Size 214M       Used  126M        Avail 72M      Use% 64%            Mounted on /boot

Comment: Do I need more space in `\boot`?

Comment: I would have thought 72M available should be enough, but apparently not; if you can increase `/boot`, then give that a shot.

Comment: How can I do that? `\boot` is at the beginnig of the space, and there is another partition after it.

Comment: After having other problems, I decided to format.